# jenkins cli - java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: jenkins-cli

First I called senkins cli without system proxy:

```
java -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://myserver:443 help
```

got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                                                                                                
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)                                                                                                        
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)                                                                                                   
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)                                                                                            
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)                                                                                                     
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)                                                                                                             
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                      
        at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaCliPort(CLI.java:203)                                                                                                               
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:126)                                                                                                                          
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)                                                                                        
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:459)                                                                                                                           
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:382)                                                                                                                            
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF                                                                                                                  
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)                                                                                
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)                                                                                        
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)                                                                                             
                at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)                                                                                                       
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)                                                                     
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)                                                                     
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:198)                                                                                    
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:419)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:398)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:394)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:383)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:375)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:351)                                                                                                     
                at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:157)                                                                                                          
                at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:130)
```

then I used `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`
and with this I got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to https://myserver:443/                                                  
        at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:266)                                                                                                                 
        at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:126)                                                                                                                        
        at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)                                                                                      
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:459)                                                                                                                         
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:382)                                                                                                                          
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"                                             
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)                                                                            
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)                                                              
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)                                                                        
                at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)                                                                  
                at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:77)                                                                               
                at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:156)                                                                                                        
                at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:130)                                                                                                                
                ... 3 more                                                                                                                                            
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"                                                      
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)                                                                                    
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)                                                                      
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)                                                                                  
        at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:264)                                                                                                                 
        ... 4 more
```

The URL comes from `https://myserver/cli/`
What is missing to able to connect to my jenkins server? using telnet I can reach the port:

```
telnet myserver 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
```